# Cannot respond to radio button change in partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I loaded a partial view containing some radiobuttons on it in my view, but when I try to respond to events from the radio button, through some jquery calls, I can't. Is it impossible to do this, or am I placing the code in the wrong place. I placed the jquery codes in the View and the partial view classes, but neither works. Can anyone help..any advice? Or code samples or links?

Code below:

Sorry...Here's the partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<Tuda.Models.PriceModel>
<table class="planTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th scope="col" abbr="Premium">PREMIUM</th>
                <th scope="col" abbr="Deluxe">DELUXE</th>
                <th scope="col" abbr="Utlmate">ULTIMATE</th>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>            
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" style="font-weight:bold">Select Plan</th>
                <td><input type="radio" name="planRadio" value="1"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="planRadio" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="planRadio" value="3"></td>               
            </tr> 
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Library Use (Includes Questions & Answers Only)</th>
                <td>Unlimited</td>
                <td>Unlimited</td>
                <td>Unlimited</td>             
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Interview Tips & Guides</th>
                <td><span ><img src="../../Images/check0.png" /></span></td>
                <td><span ><img src="../../Images/check0.png" /></span></td>
                <td><span ><img src="../../Images/check0.png" /></span></td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Problem Areas Detection</th>
                <td><span ><img src="../../Images/check0.png" /></span></td>
                <td><span ><img src="../../Images/check0.png" /></span></td>
                <td><span ><img src="../../Images/check0.png" /></span></td>               
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <th scope="row">Relevant Concepts & Terminology</th>
                <td> - </td>
                <td> - </td>
                <td><span ><img src="../../Images/check0.png" /></span></td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">User Recommended</th>
                 <td></td>
                <td><span><img src="../../Images/check0.png" /></span></td>
                <td><span><img src="../../Images/check0.png" /></span></td>             
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Validity</th>
                <td>1 Month</td>
                <td>3 Months</td>
                <td>12 Months</td>             
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>  

       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {        

$("input[name='planRadio']").change(function(){
    var planse = $("input[name='planRadio']:checked").val();
    $.get('@Url.Action(MVC.Account.AddToCartPartial())',
                { id: planse }, function (data) {
                    $('#plan').html('<p><strong>Adding to cart...</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="@Url.Content("~/images/ajax-loader1.gif")" width="54" height="55" /></p>');
                    $("#plan").html(data);
                });

});   
       </script>
```

The call to the controller isn't made

Comment: you should post some code of what is failing. Please add the jquery that isn't working along with a snippet of the partial view containing the radio button. most likely it is a selector problem, but without seeing the code it's impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: Please post some example code from your partial view, including some of the JavaScript code.

Comment: Sorry...Here's the partial view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(":radio").live("click", function () {
var inputValue = $('input:radio:checked').val(); 
});
or to keep the value of the selected Radiobutton on to hidden field
<input  type="radio" id="SelectedPlanType" rel="1"  name="Plan1" value='1' onClick="document.getElementById('hiddenfield').value=this.value"  checked="checked">
<input type="hidden" name="SelectedPlanType" value="" id="hiddenfield" />
```

Comment: This worked great. Thx. But reading the documentation of .live() in jquery, there were performance issues associated with it, and it is deprecated with jquery 1.7. It was suggested using the delegate() method which works as well, or the On() with jquery 1.7.